# how to save values in database through service api laravel

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-5

I m beginner in laravel 5, i want to know how to write service api for save the values which passing from mobile app.. Example register user in mobile app and pass those data throghu REST api to db.

Please advice

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Jzon - Laravel provide very friendly documentation for beginners like you. Most of things are explained on documentation page mentioned below - Please go through link once - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authentication-quickstart.

Lastly, quick hint for you, when ever you return an array from controller laravel default gives JSON response for you..

e.g. I am in TasksController

```
public function show($id) {
$task = Task::findOrFail($id);
return $task->toArray()
}
```

this would give Json.